# corona : memory issue?

Tags: memory, lua, memory-leaks, coronasdk

actually i'm having few question here, hope someone can help me out.

1) what is the different between

```
print(collectgarbage("count"))
```

and

```
print(system.getInfo( "textureMemoryUse" ))
```

2) i have a game that after u finish it, it will jump back to 1st page and you can just play it again, i try to out put textureMemoryUse it doesn't show me memory leak, but yet the game become more lag each time i play it, is there any other reason would make it lag other than memory leak ?

3) what is the correct way to remove an object ? what i try to do is :

```
object:removeSelf()
object = nil
```

but if i out put by using collectgarbage("count") it doesn't show any different before and after i use it.

game being lagging for each time playing have been suffer me for 2 days, really can't find what's wrong in my code, hope to get some help here.

---

here is my code on remove all the memory

```
--remove all the transition that store in a table
local k, v
for k,v in pairs(transitionTable) do
    --print(k)
    timer.cancel( v )
    v = nil; k = nil 
end

transitionTable = nil
transitionTable = {}

-- remove movie clip
playButtonAnim:removeSelf()
playButtonAnim = nil

-- remove displayGroup and it's child
displayGroup.x = display.contentHeight + 10
displayGroup.x = display.contentWidth + 10
if(displayGroup ~= nil and displayGroup.numChildren ~= nil) then
    for i=1,displayGroup.numChildren do
        print("child on display group : "..displayGroup.numChildren)
        displayGroup:remove(1)
    end
    displayGroup:removeSelf()
end
```

i try to :

```
    collectgarbage("collect")
print( "collectgarbage is " .. collectgarbage("count")  )
```

on each line and found that remove movie clip part din release any memory, i think it is not a proper way to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

1. The `collectgarbage("count")` returns the amount of memory, allocated by Lua VM. The `system.getInfo("textureMemoryUse")` returns the amount of allocated texture memory.
2. Any number of reasons, including `sleep(number_of_replays)` in the code. ;-)
3. To completely remove an object from the memory, run `collectgarbage("collect")` several times after it is deleted (one may not be enough in certain cases).

   That being said, usually it is much better to run `collectgarbage("step")` on each frame. (You may want to tune GC step and pause though.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to see a change in memory use using [collectgarbage](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-collectgarbage), you need to run `collectgarbage("collect")` before calling `collectgarbage("count")`

Answer (score 0):

1) As Alexander explains, collectgarbage("count") is the memory used by the Lua virtual machine, while system.getInfo( "textureMemoryUse" ) is the texture memory used. Put another way, the former is how much main memory Corona is using, while the latter is how much memory Corona is using on the GPU.

2) Many things could cause lag; we'd need to know a lot more than just a general description of the problem. That said, with the symptoms you describe a memory leak is the first thing I'd look for.

3) That is the correct way. Note that the numbers returned by that command can fluctuate, and it's normal for the memory usage to continually increase at the beginning until the garbage collector eventually catches up and memory usage drops. You don't so much want to check memory usage after an individual line, so much as watch your memory usage over time as the program is running.

For debugging you can put that command in an enterFrame listener to watch memory usage continuously, and then comment that part out when you're done with it.

Incidentally, on the Corona forum I posted a pretty thorough explanation of how removing objects works:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/01/14/how-do-i-tell-if-my-game-leaking#comment-16568

Comment: now i think it might not be the memory issue to cost it lag, since the memory leaking is quite less for now, after 10 times replay the memory use just increase from 190 to 210.

anyway, can i know these : 

    local highScore = require("highScore")
    highScore.Init()
    highScore = nil

consider remove properly also ? (including all the variable inside ?)

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but you never know:

you forgot to set the reference to your displayGroup to nil.
btw, if you destroy a group and have no references to the children, you don't have to destroy the children explicitely.

not properly cleaning display objects makes corona slower, that's most probably the cause of your lag.